# How do I update to the latest esp8266 arduino framework with platformio cli?

Tags: esp8266, platformio

According to the [pio docs](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/userguide/platforms/cmd_update.html#cmd-platform-update), this should work:

```sh
# pio platform update
Platform Espressif 8266
--------
Updating espressif8266                   @ 2.2.2          [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-esptoolpy                  @ 1.20600.0      [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-mkspiffs                   @ 1.200.0        [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-esptool                    @ 1.413.0        [Up-to-date]
Updating framework-arduinoespressif8266  @ 2.20502.0      [Up-to-date]
Updating toolchain-xtensa                @ 2.40802.190218 [Up-to-date]
```

That makes it look like the `espressif8266` version is up to date at 2.2.2, and the `framework-arduinoespressif8266` is up to date at 2.20502.0.  I would expect that one of these would correspond with the a recent release of the [esp8266/Arduino repo](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases), which currently sits at 2.5.2.

Is there some in-between repackaging going on?  How can I make sure that I'm using the latest version?

Comment: If you want to use the latest Arduino Core for ESP8266, see [Using Arduino Framework with Staging version](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif8266.html#using-arduino-framework-with-staging-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Codo for pointing me in the right direction.  On [the page he linked to](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif8266.html#using-arduino-framework-with-staging-version) is a link to the repo for the platformio-espressif8266-arduino platform:

https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif8266.git